# eslint error 'reject' is defined but never used no-unused-vars

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise, eslint

I'm using eslint and got an error saying that

173:32  error  'reject' is defined but never used     no-unused-vars

I'm not sure if I should remove reject or add error handling.

and here is my code and I'm not sure how to add reject either.

````
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            query_responses.forEach(({data, table_name, responseName}) => {
                Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
                    entityDBFieldNames[responseName].forEach((obj) => {
                        if(table_name === tableName) {
                            // setting values for original table
                            if(key === obj.dbFieldName) {
                                Util.setFieldValue(result, obj.entityFieldName, data[obj.dbFieldName]);
                            }
                        } else {
                            // setting values for other table
                            Util.setFieldValue(result[responseName], obj.entityFieldName, data[obj.dbFieldName]);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
            resolve();
        });
    }```
````

Comment: Why are you even using a promise here? None of that code seems to be asynchronous.

Comment: As @IceMetalPunk said there is no need to use a promise here however the lint issue you are getting is simply because you never use the `reject` parameter. Either turn off that warning or remove the parameter `return new Promise((resolve) => ...`